# ListView с кастомным DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, хочу сделать так, чтобы одна строчка имела 2 колонки: `TextBox` и `CheckBox`

Сделал я все вот так:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedColumns}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel >
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False" Width="200" Text="{Binding Item.ColumnName}"></TextBox>
                        <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="20" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"></CheckBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

И получил вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Который не совсем красивый и хотелось бы 90% отвести первому элементу, а остальное CheckBox.

Как я это могу сделать? Вроде, явное задание ширины и высоты- это не совсем корректно, так как все должно само компоноваться.

Пробовал `UniformGrid` , но он все равномерно растягивает, чего я не хочу...

Comment: Grid и ColumnDefinition вместо DockPanel? + SharedSizeGroup

Comment: @VladD Не совсем понял, как применить SharedSizeGroup  в XAML. У меня же, как я понимаю, Grid будет на каждый элемент

Comment: Оказалось, он и не нужен, ведь ширина везде и так одинаковая. Но трюк в том, чтобы растянуть внутренние `Grid`'ы на всю ширину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то у меня работает:

```xaml
<ListView MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedColumns}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False"
                                         Text="{Binding Item.ColumnName}"></TextBox>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"></CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Результат:
[image: картинка]

Comment: Еще вопросик есть немного не по теме: А не подскажите, я могу сделать так, что бы клик по любому месту DataTemplate ассоциировался с нажатием на CheckBox? Это через триггер делается? Могу задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: И еще хотелось бы как-нибудь переопределить поведение подсветки элемента списка при наведении.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну с кликом-то можно, но у вас же текстбокс, в котором можно копировать значение. Будет же конфликтовать, не?

Comment: @iluxa1810: А как именно переопределить поведение подсветки?

Comment: Ну текстбокс можно сделать ReadOnly и как-то попробовать запретить копировать значение(Пока не знаю как).

Comment: @iluxa1810: Может, тогда взять просто TextBlock? Или Label?